# How to fetch new columns from a table in a procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getcstatus(vuser_name varchar(20))
begin
select 
a.c_id, a.c_name, 
vga.* from a_c a 
inner join v_getalla vga on a.a_id=vga.a_id
where a.c_name=vuser_name
group by vga.a_id, vga.a_name, vga.c_name, vga.s_f_id, vga.s_id, s_name, vga.developer_tool_filter_id;
end$$
delimiter ;
```

In this procedure I want to fetch 4 more columns from a different table how I can fetch it?

Comment: A select in a procedure is no different to a select elsewhere - add another join for another table - does this cause you some problem (more rows than expected?) It would help if added sample data as text.

Answer (score 0):

no need to use `group by` since you are not using any `aggregation functions`.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure getcstatus(vuser_name varchar(20))
    begin
        select * 
        from a_c a 
        inner join v_getalla vga on a.a_id=vga.a_id
        where a.c_name=vuser_name
    end$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: I want to fetch 4 more columns in this procedure like k_name,k_status,k_phone,k_address from a table k_details how I can add that query in this procedure?